# pass variable from lower proc to upper proc in Tcl

Tags: variables, nested, tcl, proc

I have the following code and it prints the same value of variable c in the inner loop.

```
global c

proc one { a c } {
    for {set i $a} {$i < 10} {incr i} {
        two $c
    }
}

proc two { c } {
     incr c
     puts "Value of c is $c"
}
```

When I run it with the following inputs:

```
two 0 3
```

it prints 10 times "Value of c is 4" instead of keeping increasing the value of c inside the loop from 4 to 13.

The problem is the value of c from proc two is not passing up again to the for loop and it takes the same value from proc one parser c as 3. How can I get the desired output?

Comment: The `global` command has basically no effect at all outside of a procedure (or other thing that works like that, such as a lambda term or method body).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to pass the variable `c` from `proc one` to `proc two` *by reference* so that changes to the value of the variable are reflected back in the caller.

One way to accomplish this in `tcl` is to pass the *name* of the variable, and use the `upvar` command, as follows:

```
proc one { a c } {
    for {set i $a} {$i < 10} {incr i} {
        two c  ;# <= note: passing 'c' by name, not by value
    }
}

proc two { c_name } {
    upvar $c_name c  ;# <= note: c in this proc is using callers variable
    incr c
    puts "Value of c is $c"
}

one 0 3
```

The above produces the following output:

```
Value of c is 4
Value of c is 5
Value of c is 6
Value of c is 7
Value of c is 8
Value of c is 9
Value of c is 10
Value of c is 11
Value of c is 12
Value of c is 13
```

Comment: Tcl logically copies parameters when they're passed to procedures. This stops weird action-at-a-distance bugs, but does mean that you need to explicitly `upvar` to use a caller's variable and pass in the _variable name._ Note that Tcl's builtin commands that modify a value follow the exact same rule: anything that modifies takes a variable name as values are technically considered to be immutable. (The implementations are more efficient than this, but that's optimizations.)

Answer (score 0):

I am aware that the following does not reflect the OP's actual question, this is more like a suggestion for re-considering the design. Why use "by reference" parameter passing to begin with, here?

Why not simply stick with a functional style using `return` and continuously updating the proc-local variable `c` within the loop body's script?

```
proc one { a c } {
    for {set i $a} {$i < 10} {incr i} {
        set c [two $c] ;# <= note: passing 'c' by value
        puts "Value of c is $c"
    }
}

proc two { c_value } {
    incr c_value
    return $c_value
}

one 0 3
```

This will make `two` re-usable in different contexts, by different callers. Also:
It can be easily extended to multiple return values, variable updates using `lassign` in the caller's context (`one`).

Comment: Could you help to paste the results of code @Mrcalvin ? Thanks

Comment: @SemiCode I am afraid, I don't get the question. Can you rephrase?